# Count number of names starts with particular character in file

Tags: shell

i have the following file::

```
FirstName, FamilyName, Address, PhoneNo
```

the file is sorted according to the family name, how can i count the number of family names starts with a particular character ??

output should look like this ::

```
A: 2
B: 1
...
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{print substr($2, 1, 1)}' file|
  uniq -c|
  awk '{print $2 ": " $1}'
```

OK, no awk. Here's with sed:

```
sed s'/[^,]*, \(.\).*/\1/' file|
  uniq -c|
  sed 's/.*\([0-9]\)\+ \([a-zA-Z]\)\+/\2: \1/'
```

OK, no sed. Here's with python:

```
import csv
r = csv.reader(open(file_name, 'r'))
d = {}
for i in r:
    d[i[1][1]] = d.get(i[1][1], 0) + 1
for (k, v) in d.items():
    print "%s: %s" % (k, v)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while read -r f l r; do echo "$l"; done < inputfile | cut -c 1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: that's an interesting `read` syntax, I hadn't seen before. Can you explain it please?

Comment: @slomojo: Its a regular read; the -r is to disable backslash '\' escapes. This (read f,l,r) is basically `read first last rest`.  When field names appear after read, then read breaks the input into fields.

Answer (score 1):

**Just the Shell**

```
#! /bin/bash

##### Count occurance of familyname initial

#FirstName, FamilyName, Address, PhoneNo
exec <<EOF
Isusara, Ali,      Someplace,    022-222
Rat,     Fink,     Some Hole,    111-5555
Louis,   Frayser,  whaterver,  123-1144
Janet,   Hayes,    whoever St,      111-5555
Mary,    Holt,     Henrico VA,   222-9999
Phillis, Hughs,    Some Town,   711-5525
Howard,  Kingsley, ahahaha,   222-2222
EOF



while read first family rest
do
  init=${family:0:1}
  [ -n "$oinit" -a $init != "$oinit" ]  && {
      echo $oinit : $count
      count=0
  }
  oinit=$init
  let count++
done

echo $oinit : $count
```

**Running**

```
frayser@gentoo ~/doc/Answers/src/SH/names $ sh names.sh
A : 1
F : 2
H : 3
K : 1
frayser@gentoo ~/doc/Answers/src/SH/names $
```

To read from a file, remove the here document, and run:

```
chmod +x names.sh
./names.sh <file
```

Comment: Definitely bash specific, but wow, I did not know that it was possible to use `&&` and braces like that, or the `let` command to increment a counter. +1

Comment: I think only the "let count++" is Bash specific.  KSH has "let count+=1".  Funny but KSH on Linux runs this script with the "++" in it; but I could not find that documented for POSIX.  The */bin/ksh* I have is: "sh (AT&T Research) 1993-12-28 s+"  The `&& {}` is an old but common Bourne shell idiom.

Answer (score 0):

The "hard way" — no use of awk or sed, exactly as asked for. If you're not sure what any of these commands mean, you should definitely look at the [man page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for each one.

```
INTERMED=`mktemp`       # Creates a temporary file
COUNTS_L=`mktemp`       # A second...
COUNTS_R=`mktemp`       # A third...

cut -d , -f 2 |         # Extracts the FamilyName field only

tr -d '\t ' |           # Deletes spaces/tabs

cut -c 1 |          # Keeps only the first character
                # on each line

tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' |    # Capitalizes all letters

sort |              # Sorts the list

uniq -c > $INTERMED     # Counts how many of each letter
                # there are

cut -c1-7 $INTERMED |       # Cuts out the LHS of the temp file
tr -d ' ' > $COUNTS_R       # Must delete the padding spaces though


cut -c9- $INTERMED > $COUNTS_L  # Cut out the RHS of the temp file

# Combines the two halves into the final output in reverse order
paste -d ' ' /dev/null $COUNTS_R | paste -d ':' $COUNTS_L -

rm $INTERMED $COUNTS_L $COUNTS_R    # Cleans up the temp files
```

Comment: You shouldn't encourage that sort of thing :)

Comment: Exactly. It wouldn't surprise me if the awk, sed, and python solutions turned out to be faster. It's bad enough that doing it this way, two or three temporary files are easily necessary. So that's why one shouldn't limit himself from using awk or sed.

Answer (score 0):

awk one-liner:

```
awk '
    {count[substr($2,1,1)]++} 
    END {for (init in count) print init ": " count[init]}
' filename
```

Comment: Technically, that's more than one line :-p

Comment: meh, remove the newlines if you wish. Bash will consider that a one-liner, a command with 2 arguments: the first argument 
 just happens to have newline chars in it.

Answer (score 0):

Prints the how many words start with each letter:

for i in {a..z}; do echo -n "$i:"; find path/to/folder -type f -exec sed "s/ /\n/g" {} \; | grep ^$i | wc -c | awk '{print $0}'; done